# How can I build a CSV file from a GridView in Visual Basic?

Tags: vb.net, gridview, csv

I have a report I'm generating in VB.Net that is being displayed in a GridView. The data is pulled from SQL based on some constraints the user enters and can be any size, depending on these. I would like to be able to take these values from the grid and put them into a CSV for a downloadable report without rerunning my SQL select (I know how to build one that way), preferably in a generic fashion so this can be easily reused.
Here's what I have currently. It makes a CSV, but only the headers are present.

```
Protected Sub btnExcel_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnExcel.Click
    Dim strOutput As New StringBuilder

    Response.ContentType = "application/csv"
    ' Remove the charset from the Content-Type header.
    Response.Charset = ""
    ' Turn off the view state.
    Me.EnableViewState = False
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "filename=report.csv;")

    strOutput.AppendLine(GetCSVLine(grid.HeaderRow.Cells))
    For Each row As GridViewRow In grid.Rows
        strOutput.AppendLine(GetCSVLine(row.Cells))
    Next


    Response.Write(strOutput)

    Response.Flush()

    Response.End()
End Sub

Private Function GetCSVLine(cells As TableCellCollection) As String
    Dim returnValue As String = ""

    For Each cell As TableCell In cells
        returnValue += cell.Text + ","
    Next

    Return returnValue
End Function
```

And the aspx page

```
    <asp:GridView ID="grid" runat="server" EnableModelValidation="True" AutoGenerateColumns = "false">
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Name")%>'/>&nbsp;
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Location">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblLocation" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Location")%>'/>&nbsp;
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
<!-- There are a few more fields after this, using the same structure -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, running off the top of my head here but I think that because each row contains a set of `Label` controls which have the text inside of them, you can't use a straight `cell.Text` against the table cells to get the contents out.

What you may have to do is use the [`FindControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/486wc64h.aspx) method against each row to get the relevant control out and then access the properties of each control that you retrieve to get the data which you need to push out in the CSV. Something like:

```
For Each row As GridViewRow In grid.Rows
    'In each row, find the control which contains the data and then get the text of the control
    Dim nameLabel As Label = CType(row.FindControl("lblName"), Label)
    Dim nameValue As String = nameLabel.Text

    'Once you have all the values, write out the StringBuilder like you are doing already
Next
```

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way to do this more generically so if I only have one label, in each cell, I don't have to know the name?

Comment: You could iterate through the [Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.controls.aspx) collection of each row and do a check against the Type of the control to see if it is a label. You could also extract the Label out of the `Controls` collection by using LINQ

Comment: Thank you so much. Our customer no longer wants this report, but I'm sure this will come in handy when in a few weeks they change their minds.